# Space changes the type?

Tags: f#

I typed the following code with extension Ionide-fsharp and its type is `int -> int -> int -> int`

```
let test a b c = a / b + c
```

However, if I remove the space before `c`

```
let test a b c = a / b +c
let test a b c = a/b +c
```

The type becomes `int -> (int -> int) -> int -> int`?

However, the following expression gets the original type.

```
let test a b c = a/b+c
```

Visual studio got the same result. It seems `+c` is treated as `c` in F# expression.

Comment: What does `-c` do? Make sense now? Think of `c` and syntactic sugar for `+c`, but `-c` does not have syntactic sugar because it would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your assumption is correct: a plus in front of a term without a space is treated as an unary operator, not a binary one. Same will happen with a minus sign, by the way.

After that is determined, there is only one way to interpret the rest: `b +c` must be an application of function `b` to argument `+c`, therefore `b` must be a function that takes an `int`. The result of this application is used as a denominator in a division, so it must have type `int` as well. Therefore, `b` must be `int -> int`.

Comment: It's so easy to accidentally remove the space. And a+b, a *b added the confusion. I prefer to a (+b) if unary operator is needed.

Comment: Sure, it's easy, but the compiler will instantly catch it.